# Cant understand definition of index of center

Tags: group-theory

$Z(G)$ is not trivial and $G$ is of order $p^2,$ where $p$ is prime.
Assume that $|Z(G)|$ is $p.$

Why is it that $|Z(G)| = [G:Z(G)] = p$??
I can't picture how the number of left cosets of $Z(G)$ in $G$ is somehow exactly p.

Comment: **(1)** If $H\le G$ then $|G|=[G:H]|H|$. There are $[G:H]$ cosets, each with $|H|$ elements, which make up $G$. **(2)** For nonabelian $p$-groups, $Z(G)$ must be proper and nontrivial. **(3)** If $|G|=p^2$, it's actually **not** possible for $Z(G)$ to have order or index $p$, since this would mean $G/Z(G)$ is nontrivial cyclic, which is impossible. This is a standard exercise, though I suspect you may be quoting a source covering material near this exercise ...

Answer (score 1):

Do you know Lagrange's Theorem? This is immediate from this theorem's proof, just applied to the particular subgroup of the center. Let $H \leq G$ be a subgroup of a finite group $G$.  Then $|H|$ divides $|G|$ and the index of $H$ in $G$ (the number of cosets of $H$ in $G$) is $\frac{|G|}{|H|}$.  So for your case, this just says $\frac{p^2}{p}$ which is $p$.

Comment: (Note the caveat that it's actually impossible for $Z(G)=p$ when $|G|=p^2$.)

Comment: but how do you derive that the size of Z(g) is somehow equal to its index in G, is it an observation or definition

Comment: Yeah, I am assuming it is part of a proof to show why it would need to be abelian, but I am not sure of the context of this question. To then conclude that G/Z(G) is cyclic which makes $G$ abelian which means $Z(G)=G$, but I am not really sure.

Comment: The size being equal to its index is sort of a red herring.  It is only true because $p^2/p$ is $p$ again.  The index is the number of cosets.  Here, cosets of $Z(G)$ partitions $G$ with $p^2$ elements into $p$ cosets each with $p$ elements in it.